# How to parameterize a SignalR route?

Tags: .net, url-routing, signalr

I would like to be able to configure the SignalR route to have an MVC-style route parameter like so:

/{community}/signalr

This will allow the signalr requests to parallel the rest of my application's url structure and make authorization much simpler. I suspect it is possible to jigger the Owin routing to do this somehow, but I'm not really familiar with it. Is this something that can be done fairly easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you are asking. You can set a `qs` parameter however.

```
$.connection.hub.qs = { "community" : communityName };
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() { /* ... */ });
```

This means that each request made to SignalR will have "&community={community name}" appended to it.

Inside a `Hub` you can access the community name through the `Context`:

```
Context.QueryString["community"]
```